# Create file command in batch files (*.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a file named "new text document.txt" in the folder `%tv%` using a batch file ( `*.bat`). This is my batch file:

```
set tv=D:\prog\arpack96\ARPACK\SRC
cd "%tv%"
@CON >> "new text document.txt"
set tv=
```

Although I can really create the file in `%tv%`, but when I run the above batch file, I will get an error message saying

> ' ' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program
>   or batch file.

Is there anyway to get rid of this error message? Or I am creating the file using the wrong command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get a truly empty file without having to provide user interaction, you can use the `set /p` command with a little trickery:

```
set tv=c:\documents and settings\administrator
cd "%tv%"
<nul >"new text document.txt" (set /p tv=)
```

The `set /p` asks the user for input into the `tv` variable after outputting the prompt after the `=` character.

Since the prompt is empty, no prompt is shown. Since you're reading from nul, it doesn't wait for user interaction. And you can store the empty string straight into `tv` thus removing the need to unset it.

---

Actually, after some more thought, there's an easier way. I've used that `set /p` trick in the past since it's the only way I know of echoing text without a newline being added (great for progress bars in the console). But if all you want is an empty file, you can probably get away with:

```
copy /y nul "new text document.txt"
```

The `copy` simply copies the contents of the `nul` device (effectively an empty file) to your new file name. The `/y` is to ensure it's overwritten without bothering the user.

Comment: Well, it's *a* correct answer, it may not be the only one :-)

Comment: I usually used either `type nul >` or `copy nul`. But I learned about that `set /p` trick much later here anyway :).

Answer (score 4):

Create an empty file from a *.bat file - this worked for me.

```
echo off > test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
type nul > file.txt
```

file.txt should be created empty

or [paxdiablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046502/create-file-command-in-batch-files-bat/2046587#2046587)

Comment: I don't want user interaction; all I want is to just silently create an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

con is the windows specialized file name and it should not be used.

copy con >> filename.txt

shall ask you to enter the text and you can save the text by typing Ctrl Z.

Comment: I don't want to be asked to enter the text; I want a file to be created silently at the specified location