# When appending to a file using Windows batch commands, how to append immediately after the next word in the file?

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting, batch-file

When appending to a file using Windows batch commands, how to append immediately after the next word in the file?

For example, these commands

```
echo here is the date of > c:\arun.txt
date /t >> c:\arun.txt
```

write the following text to the arun.txt file:

> here is the date of
>   29-03-2010

But I want the output to be like this:

> here is the date of 29-03-2010

How to avoid carrage return while appending?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `echo` output always includes a trailing new line. To output text without a trailing new line, you can use the `set /p` trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/underused-features-of-windows-batch-files/374361#374361) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046502/create-file-command-in-batch-files-bat/2046587#2046587):

```
< nul (set /p s=Today is ) > c:\arun.txt
date /t >> c:\arun.txt
```

But in this specific case, you can simply use the `%date%` variable instead of `date /t`, as `%date%` uses the same format:

```
echo Today is %date% > c:\arun.txt
```

Comment: `%date%` is no environment variable. It's merely a pseudo-variable expanded to the current date by the shell.

Comment: thank u .do u know how to append a empty line in the text file ?

Comment: @Arunachalam: Try `echo.>>file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

you can store to a variable and append

```
C:\test>set s=here is today's date
C:\test>for /F "tokens=*" %i in ('date /t') do set d=%i    
C:\test>set d=Tue 03/30/2010    
C:\test>echo %d%%s%
Tue 03/30/2010 here is today's date
```